# Mathematical structures with name referring to a country

Tags: reference-request, terminology, definition, big-list

I am looking for a list of mathematical structures (not theorems) that refer to a country or nationality.

I only know of Polish spaces and Polish groups. Does anyone have other examples?

Note: many of these can be found when looking at Olympiad contests since they often decide to name structures after the city or country where the event is hosted, but I would like examples found in the literature.

Comment: I know exactly one other example off the top of my head, which is "Japanese ring" (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagata_ring).

Comment: Chinese remainder theorem http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem (but it is theorem)

Comment: Well there's always Polish notation haha. Lots of Polish stuff.

Comment: Do Poles in complex analysis count? :D

Comment: Latin square. Greco-Latin square.

Comment: Not entirely fitting the question as it's neither a country nor a structure, but the field of *tropical geometry* is so named because it was pioneered by a Brazilian. You know, as in the "tropics". Yes, I think it's kind of silly too.

Comment: Catalan numbers ar *not* really an example because the name is derived from Eugène Charles Catalan

Comment: There is such a thing as a "cuban prime" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuban_prime), but they have to do with cubes, not Cuba. Oh, well.

Comment: There's an exercise in Stanley which asks you to identify the sequence "un, dos, tres, quatre, cinc, sis, set, vuit, nou, deu..." which are "of course" the numbers in the Catalan language.  (I say "of course" because I suspect that  few people reading this would recognize them, but many might recognize that these are clearly numbers in some Romance language.)

Comment: [Egyptian fractions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1272441/mathematical-structures-with-name-reffering-to-a-country), [Dutch book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dutch_book)

Comment: Arabic numerals, also called Indo-Arabic, since they were first developed in India.

Comment: [Mayan numerals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maya_numerals)

Comment: Hungarian algorithm? Hawaiian earring? Byzantine fault?

Comment: I'm surprised no one yet said Roman Numerals, so named when Rome was the name of a country as well as the name of a city.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An answer was already given and accepted but I thought it might be cool to share this combinatorial structure; which I found in Richard Stanley's book Enumerative Combinatorics: [Aztec Diamonds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aztec_diamond). Note I am taking liberty to use the word Aztec as in the Aztec empire.

Aztec diamonds were introduced by Noam Elkies, Greg Kuperberg, Michael Larsen and James Propp in 1991. The original paper can be found in the arxiv [Alternating sign matrices and domino tilings](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9201305.pdf). Following the paper: The Aztec diamond of order $n$ is the union of those lattice squares $[a,a + 1] \times [b,b + 1] ⊂ \mathbb{R}^{2}$ with $a,b\in Z$ that lie completely inside the tilted square $\{(x,y) : |x| + |y| \leq n + 1\}.$ Several proofs are given that show the number of [domino tilings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domino_tiling) of the Aztec diamond of order $n$ is $2^{n(n+1)/2}$ a result the authors refer to as the Aztec Diamond Theorem. Apparently there is a connection between Aztec Diamonds and the square-ice-model *of Lieb*.

Answer (score 1):

Another example are [American puts, and American calls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Option_style#American_and_European_options)

Comment: [European Ooptions](https://www.investopedia.com/articles/optioninvestor/08/american-european-options.asp) ?

Comment: Asian and Bermudan options also exist